# parse nested hash into RUBY to print output, without taking duplicate values

Tags: ruby, loops, parsing, hash

I have a nested hash and I am able to iterate it and print the section and the field values from the hash. I'm trying to iterate over this nested hash to create a steps guide, I want to create a file with the information and the output file to have the output written like:

```
steps_guide [section]elemento1 [section]elemento2 [section]elemento3
steps_guide [section]elemento2 [section]elemento3 [section]elemento4
....
steps_guide [section]radio [section]xenon [section]aluminio
steps_guide [section]xenon [section]aluminio [section]boro
```

If a section name is duplicated in other elementos I only need to print something like:

```
steps_guide expected_[section_duplicated]elemento1 [section]elemento2 [section]elemento3
```

and not print that section again and print the next element, and this for all the nested hash. Here is the source data.

```
_Data =[
    {
        "name": "script",
        "elements": [
            {
                "name": "unknown group",
                "headers": {
                    "map": {}
                },
                "agent": "",
                "bottom_comments": [],
                "checks": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento1",
                        "section": "control_psd",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento2",
                        "section": "control_psd",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento3",
                        "section": "control_ptt",
                        "value": "0",
                    },

                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento4",
                        "section": "control_save",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "control_relay",
                        "field": "elemento5",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "control_relay",
                        "field": "elemento6",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "control_reply",
                        "field": "elemento7",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "plc_status",
                        "field": "elemento8",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "plc_status",
                        "field": "elemento9",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "section": "plc_value",
                        "field": "elemento10",
                        "value": "0",

                    },
                    {
                        "type": "condiciones",
                        "elementos": [
                            {
                                
                                "table": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "regresion",
                                        "name": "radio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "regresion",
                                        "name": "xenon",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "update",
                                        "name": "aluminio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "cont",
                                        "name": "boro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "container",
                                        "name": "oro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "after",
                                        "name": "bromo",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "section": "after",
                                        "name": "oxigeno",
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a line for each item in the ``elements`` array that contains all the ``section`` and ``field`` values from the ``checks`` array, but you want to filter out duplicate section values. Is that correct? For a duplicated section (like 'control_psd' above) do you want to keep the first value, the last value, or all values?

Comment: exactly, i want to keep all the values i dont want to modify it, i just want to print it in the output but just if the section repeats, just print it one time